# After installing Ubuntu, Windows laptop will not boot and repair fails

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

So I have this Lenovo Y510P laptop with Windows 8.1 installed on it. Everything worked fine until two days ago, when I tried to install Ubuntu.

I successfully installed Ubuntu and after few minutes of using it, the image froze and I tried to restart the machine. After I restarted the machine I noticed that my OS won't boot any more, so I tried to manually select it in the Boot Menu.

Unfortunately, I received these errors :

```
Windows Boot Manager boot failed
Windows Boot Manager boot failed
Ubuntu boot failed
```

Ok, so I started searching different solutions on the internet and I also tried a few things :

- I tried to repair my laptop using the Windows 8 installer, I selected Troubleshoot Menu, and I selected "Refresh your pc", and I receive this : `The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again`. After that, I selected "Reset your pc" and I received this : `Unable to reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing.`
- After these try-outs, I decided to check if I can make a new installation of Windows, and I cant, it says : `We couldn't find any drives. To get a storage driver, click Load driver`. So now I thought that it may be a problem with my hard-disk, I thought that my laptop wouldn't recognize it or something like that, so I accessed the command prompt and I used the command list disk, and it shows me just the size of the USB on which I have my windows installation, no other disks. After that I checked if my hard disk is being recognized in BIOS and it is.

I tried to use the automatic repair from the troubleshoot -> advanced tab, and now I can't access the Windows 8 installer because I receive this error :

```
Recovery, your pc needs to be repaired. 
The Boot Configuration Data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system. 
File :\Boot\Bcd, Error code: 0xc0000098
Does anyone know how to approach this problem?
EDIT : I tried all methods from repair, including automatic repair. The thing is that when i plug in my usb with the windows 8 installer on it, if I go to repair->advanced->command prompt and I try to do a chkdsk or a list disk it shows me just the size of my USB, no other disk is found, I ran few commands for checking my disk and building a boot enviroment but it's still not working, the windows installer isn't detecting my hard disk.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the installation media/DVD for Windows, you can try Startup Repair. Put the media in the drive, start the system from the DVD, and click "Repair Your Computer." It should attempt to repair the BCD (Boot Configuration Database) on your system.